# Определить относительную загрузку сети (в %) за контрольный период времени

Tags: сеть, wireshark

Никак не могу разобраться в формуле, которую мне дали. Я, с помощью Wireshark, составил таблицу, которую от меня требовали. Теперь, используя данные этой таблицы, мне нужно определить относительную загрузку сети (в %) за контрольный период времени по формуле :
[image: формула]

Не понимаю, какие данные нужно вставлять в формулу.

Таблица:

[image: таблица]

Скорость интернета :

[image: скорость сети]

Comment: Загрузка = среднюю скорость делите на пропускную. при 100mb = 0.297/100 = 0.297% ; а если у вас 1Gb то 0.297/1000 = 0.0297%

Comment: Огромное спасибо ! Теперь понял )